# static global variable V static global Class variable

Tags: c++, static, global-variables

Which is way to declare a string const is more recommended?

1. Is to declare the global variable at file scope.
2. To declare it global to the class.

The variable will be used only in the class member functions. I am tending to feel 2 is better since it is specific to the class member functions only.

```
A.cpp
---------------------
static const std::string hello_str = "Hello";

void A::print()
{
    std::cout << hello_str;
}
```

(OR)

```
A.h
---------------------
class A{
public:
    static const std::string hello_str;
    void print();
}

A.cpp
---------------------
const std::string A::hello_str = "Hello";

void A::print()
{
    std::cout << A::hello_str;
}
```

Edit -1:

Let me say that the contents of hello_str can change. Eg. the string is updated manually by the developer whenever he makes a change to the file.

In this case, would it make sense to keep the variable initialization inside a function?
It may not be clear/evident for the user to update the string. If it was kept global to the file (1) or to the class (2) then other developers can "identify" & modify this string.

Given the above use case, do you still recommend having a function to return the string? Or can I use the class level static variable (with private access specifier)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an anonymous namespace is another option:

A.cpp

```
namespace {
  const std::string hello_str("Hello");
}

void A::print() {
    std::cout << hello_str;
}
```

but you should really wrap that in a function for deferred initialization.

that would take the form:

```
A.h
---------------------
class A{
public:
    static const std::string& hello_str();
    void print();
}

A.cpp
---------------------
const std::string& A::hello_str() {
  static const std::string str("Hello"); // << constructed on first call of A::hello_str()
  return str;
}

void A::print() {
    std::cout << A::hello_str();
}
```

in this case, you could also simply return by value, and avoid the static/global altogether. your std c++ library implementation may use what is call "small string optimization" -- if so, no heap allocation would be required to create or move a string this short.

also note that your two examples are not the same; one is effectively private, and the other is publicly visible.

ultimately, you should use *neither* approach you have proposed. consider a static within a function for lazy initialization, or (even better in many cases) returning by value.

to answer your original question: i favor the declaration inside the class, but private. i find this easier to maintain in the event implementations shift around. and of course, if that static in the cpp is somehow accessible to outside implementations, then you might want to also declare it as private inside the class so others cannot access it.

Comment: Can U pls explain "one is effectively private, and the other is publicly visible." - I thought both are 1 & 2 are public. 

"i favor the declaration inside the class, but private." - Understand this part, that only member func access it and not from main (other class' member func)

"i find this easier to maintain in the event implementations shift around. and of course, if that static in the cpp is somehow accessible to outside implementations, then you might want to also declare it as private inside the class so others cannot access it." - Can U pls explain this and/or provide me an example?

Comment: @KingkongJnr it's just the obvious case: in #1, the `static` may be accessed by anything in A.cpp which does not precede it. if A.cpp contains only definitions of class A, then it is what i referred to as "effectively private". the visibility and access to the static is *restricted*. it is a common approach C programmers use for their private functions/data. for example: `main()` could not access that static, unless main were defined in A.cpp.

Comment: @KingkongJnr `print`, declared `private` and foo is public here: `class A { \n public: void foo(); \n private: \n void print(); \n };`

Answer (score 2):

Simple rule:

- The `string` logically belongs to the class so it should be a class member.
- All the instances of the class share the same string hence it belongs to the class and not an specific instance of class(all instances share same string), so make it a `static` member.

This gives you the advantage that:

- Only the class members which need to access the string will have access, unlike if you declare it as an global string.